# How to align the x-axis on Y=0 in R?

Tags: r, plot

I observed that the x axes of a `plot` doesn't cross the y axes at `0`.

Why?

How can I fix that?

Example:

```
plot(mtcars$mpg, ylim=c(0,50))
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, R extends the axes by 4% on either end around the limits: from `?par`,

> ‘xaxs’ The style of axis interval calculation to be used for the
>             x-axis.  Possible values are ‘"r"’, ‘"i"’, ‘"e"’, ‘"s"’,
>             ‘"d"’.  The styles are generally controlled by the range of
>             data or ‘xlim’, if given.
>             Style ‘"r"’ (regular) first extends the data range by 4
>             percent at each end and then finds an axis with pretty labels
>             that fits within the extended range.
>             Style ‘"i"’ (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels
>             that fits within the original data range.

(`yaxs` does the same thing for the y-axis).

You can use

```
plot(mtcars$mpg, ylim=c(0,50), yaxs="i")
```